# Search array of objects in a Mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection which contains an array of objects. I know how to use `$elemMatch` to search using one object as a parameter but I need a way to use values of multiple objects in the array.

Sample collection:

```
{ '_id' : ObjectId('5788804292a1c428cd5377ff'), 'index' : 'a', 'data' : [ { 'value0' : 'data_a' }, { 'value1' : 'data_b' }, { 'value2' : 'data_c' } ] }
{ '_id' : ObjectId('5788804b92a1c428cd537800'), 'index' : 'b', 'data' : [ { 'value0' : 'data_a' }, { 'value1' : 'data_x' }, { 'value2' : 'data_c' } ] }
{ '_id' : ObjectId('5788805592a1c428cd537801'), 'index' : 'c', 'data' : [ { 'value0' : 'data_a' }, { 'value1' : 'data_x' }, { 'value2' : 'data_y' } ] }
```

How do I specify a search criteria to match all records which match either of the following conditions:

1. `value1 == data_b` and `value2 == data_c`
2. `value1 == data_x` and `value2 == data_y`

I've tried the following with `find` but no results are returned:

```
{'data': {$elemMatch: {$in: [{'value1': 'data_b', 'value2': 'data_c'}, {'value1':'data_x', 'value2': 'data_y'}]}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to match:

```
({value1: data_b} AND {value2: data_c}) OR ({value1: data_x} AND {value2: data_y})
```

then you could use this query, which is a direct translation of the above logic:

```
db.collection.find(
    {$or: [
        {'data.value1': 'data_b', 'data.value2': 'data_c'},
        {'data.value1': 'data_x', 'data.value2': 'data_y'}
    ]}
)
```

which should return two documents from your example:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5788804292a1c428cd5377ff"),
  "index": "a",
  "data": [
    {
      "value0": "data_a"
    },
    {
      "value1": "data_b"
    },
    {
      "value2": "data_c"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5788805592a1c428cd537801"),
  "index": "c",
  "data": [
    {
      "value0": "data_a"
    },
    {
      "value1": "data_x"
    },
    {
      "value2": "data_y"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that queries with a top-level `$or` operator, **all terms of the `$or` operator must have an index**. Otherwise MongoDB will perform a collection scan, which will be a performance issue and could move your working set out of memory.

Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or for more details.

Comment: Yup, that worked. Thank you for your response. Based on your response, I ended up using `$or` and `$and` with the array in conjunction with `$elemMatch` (the real objects are much more complex and the collection above was just a simplified example).

Answer (score 0):

`{'data': {$all: [{'value1': 'data_b', 'value2': 'data_c'}, {'value1':'data_x', 'value2': 'data_y`'}]}}

Use $all

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't think that is correct. AFAIK, $all will match all elements of an array against the specified field. In my case, the field (i.e. `data`) is an array of objects, which I want to search using the values of the objects.